# Bind a MouseDoubleclick to a button wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Hi  I have form with 2 listboxes and 2 buttons "MoveLeft-MoveRight

When double clicking on the button I need to associate an event to a command.

I manage to successufully do for one but I can I do the same for each button

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=MoveRightCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I cannot do

```
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="BtnLeft.MouseDoubleClick">
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="BtnRight.MouseDoubleClick">
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Check in code, which button was clicked. Mouse-Click-Events dont differ, which button was clicked

Comment: what about xaml via command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the eventtrigger under each listbox